# SSRS Deployment

Tags: sql-server, ssrs

I have developed and deploy my reports on report server in LAN. but I want to deploy my reports on report server which is not in LAN. means I need a setup  or package which can run at client end without showing my report layout and query written.

How I can do this ?

Comment: What do you want to do? Deploy your report to a remote SSRS server not on your LAN (which is possible), or do you want clients to run end user reports (which is also possible)?

Answer (score 1):

If you are only deploying a few reports, it is possible to manually upload them to the SSRS server which is not on your LAN by uploading them to the SSRS site through the web interface by simply using a web browser. This is not practical for a large number of reports, where the meaning of "large number" is a personal choice.

You might also want to review [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056799/automating-ssrs-report-deployment) on stackoverflow, which covers some of the same ground -- "what other ways can I deploy SSRS reports?"